# How to make chromium remember window size and position (linux / gnome)?

Tags: linux, gnome, chromium, fullscreen

When I start the chromium browser on Arch Linux with GNOME 3, it starts fullscreen.

How can I achieve that chromium remembers window size and position? And is chromium or GNOME responsible for the fullscreen start?

### edit

It is not only chromium. If I leave only some space between window and 'screen edge', like on the screenshot, firefox, nautilus, chromium and perhaps others, too, start fullscreen next time. Perhaps a gnome feature, I don't know.

[image]

It is annoying when I want to have empathy (chat) on the right side next to chromium. With smaller windows, the position and size is remembered correctly.

Comment: Chromium starts in the same size & placed window on XFCE for me, so does Firefox... maybe gnome is misbehaving. All config files are writeable?